# Remove and/or rename fields in Sitecore JSS via template definitions

Tags: jss

Is there is way to remove or rename a field in Sitecore JSS via template definitions?

Even with an ID on the field, it won't rename. Deleting the field object will not delete the field in Sitecore.

We want to use code-first templates, but this could give some problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import very specifically does not rename or delete items. Per [the docs](http://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/working-disconnected/import-process):

> ### Import does not purge unknown items
>
> If a template or route is removed from the manifest, it is not deleted from Sitecore on the next import.

If you want to follow default conventions and have Sitecore look entirely like your manifest and nothing else, consider using *wipe* import (`-w` on the CLI) which will purge imported items before recreating them all. Wipe will prompt by default; `--unattendedWipe` will disable the prompt for CI scenarios.

If you're going to get advanced with your items though, use an item serialization tool to maintain the app's state from the Sitecore side.